# Is there an official SO version of the WMD editor available for download?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, editor, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where's the WMD editor open source project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/wheres-the-wmd-editor-open-source-project)

I'd like to know if the version of Markdown that SO uses, with the same header with blank background and the same help button in the top right corner, is available for download.

Comment: Why to vote for closing this question after it has already been answered? :)

Comment: Answering a question doesn't prevent it being closed - in this case the votes are for it being migrated to Meta. The answers will be get migrated as well. I'm not 100% sure myself which is why I'm not voting

Comment: now moved to http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [wmd-new](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/) at Google Code or the [Stack Overflow fork](http://github.com/derobins/wmd) of WMD at GitHub.

[Here's a quick demo](http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/wmd/wmd-test.html) of wmd-new (pulled from GitHub), with the styles slightly modified to look closer to those on SO. There are still a few differences (hover color on buttons, help question mark, etc), but it's really just a matter of tweaking the styles; the styles on Stack Overflow are built into their main stylesheet, and haven't all been applied to wmd-new.

In order to change the look of the buttons, or their hover states, you'll need to edit the image sprite that contains them all. That can be found in `images/wmd-buttons.png`, with the source Photoshop document in `images/wmd-buttons.psd`.

You shouldn't have to edit any JavaScript to get it to look like Stack Overflow, I don't believe, unless you want to get the textarea resizer, which you can find as a [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the http://wmd-new.googlecode.com/svn/trunk repository is empty.

Comment: The Google Code project is just there as a home page and bug tracker, not for code repository. Note the sentence "Actual development takes place on github (see links)."

Comment: @Brian: Ah.. so it's the same version as Rex and CMS said. I think I'll need to style it myself

Comment: The only difference in style I can see between that one and the one on SO is a few background colors and the help question mark.

Comment: @Brian: Yes but impressively there's no CSS to change these backgrounds and the help image. I tried modifying it in the original version of WMD and I didn't find that trivial, that's why I'm asking for a modified version.

Comment: No CSS to change the backgrounds and help image? Look in `wmd.css`; there are various `background-color` properties you can change. I've posted an example of modifying some of the backgrounds in my question. The help button is part of the image sprite you can find in `images/wmd-buttons.png`, with the source Photoshop image in `images/wmd-buttons.psd`. You will have to modify that if you want to change the button images, and re-export the `.png` (or just modify the `.png` directly, but that's less ideal).

Comment: @Brian: Oh god, it's my fault. The downloadable version of the source code in the link you posted does not contain any wmd.css, but the trunk version of the files have. They made some modifications because the last versions I checked also did not expose any css. The styles were made throuh javascript. I pretty much appreciate your attention and thank you for the help.

Comment: Adding new list items is horribly broken under Chrome and doesn't really work right under Safari. Is there a way to turn off the broken "electric list" function?

Comment: @Brian Campbell , May i know how could i make it able to upload the image to imgur from the editor ? like what stackoverflow does ? Thx for reply

Comment: @Spencer Lim: I don't know, I haven't looked at wmd in a long time. I'm not sure if they've published any of their more recent changes, like uploading to imgur; it looks to me like the project on GitHub hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: @Brian Campbell, Thx anyway =D i will change the way seem there is no much support to imgur ~.~

Answer (score 2):

The StackOverflow branch of the WMD editor is hosted on [github](http://github.com/derobins/wmd).

More info:

- [WMD Editor Reverse Engineered](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/)

Comment: This github editor keeps the theme of the official WMD-Editor =/

Comment: Oh, I see, then you can give a look to the style that SO uses, you can check the all.css file: http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=5934 look for all the selectors that start with the `wmd-` prefix...

Comment: Just copied all these styles to the page I'm testing and it doesn't work. I knew that it wouldn't work because I knew that the background color and the button image were being set through javascript. I tried changing the javascript but it didn't get cross-browser.

Answer (score 2):

Stackoverflow branches of WMD are maintained on GitHub [here](http://github.com/cky/wmd) and [here](http://github.com/derobins/wmd). If you have trouble making a specific customization, start a new question describing what you've attempted and what isn't working and you'll get plenty of help.

Comment: Thanks.. but the styles are not as the SO editor.. If I can't find an already modified version I'll try to do it myself :) Actually I already tried and got not so cross browser results.

Answer (score 1):

[The most active branch](http://github.com/ananthakumaran/wmd/)
[v2 download page](http://github.com/ananthakumaran/wmd/downloads)