# Where's the WMD editor open source project?

Tags: discussion, editor

Where is the open source project for the WMD editor used on this site?

Comment: See also: [What's the deal with the WMD editor?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36179/162705) and [Will the WMD repository ever be updated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75677/162705)

Comment: Related blog post: *[WMD Editor Reverse Engineered](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/10/wmd-editor-reverse-engineered/)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since Google Code archive all repositories, pagedown now lives at GitHub https://github.com/balpha/pagedown.

As of August 2011, it now lives under http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/. This version is identical to the version running on the Stack Exchange sites, except for a few Stack Exchange-specific additions (e.g spoilers) that are not included.

It is a completely refactored version; the old one at http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/ is no longer maintained.

Comment: Jeff, is that project dead or is it still alive? The github version has a few bugs, and the Google code site appears to be inactive. Are there any plans to continue this? Also, is the version SO using open source and available to the public? (I'm assuming it's different than the Google code / gitHub versions since the bugs have been fixed)

Comment: @mel it is alive, there will be more activity on it soon. Just working through a backlog.

Comment: I have scowered that google code page and can't for the life of me find the github link. Where might we be able to find it?

Comment: @rock the google code link is correct and contains the latest code. We tend to use Google Code for consistency, never Github.

Comment: I found it after posting. For some reason I neglected to click on the "browse" button, and just stayed on the checkout button. Thanks Jeff

Comment: Are the StackExchange pagedown/wmd help interfaces available anywhere? i.e. the tabular help content and bouncing of the icons, would make for a good plugin if not wrapped into core.

Comment: there is nothing to download in first link, so would you provide new source

Comment: @mayank try http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/

Comment: @JeffAtwood it seems like google code "is shutting down" so they basically archived the pagedown project. I exported to github here: https://github.com/maniator/pagedown

Comment: It seems the [stack exchange github page](http://stackexchange.github.io/) has changed and pagedown is now on github here: [balpha/pagedown](https://github.com/balpha/pagedown)

Comment: @UftouLaTouffe in cases like this it's better to edit the link ourselves, users with less than 2k rep can suggest such edit, and it would be most likely approved.

Comment: `http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/` is 404 now (Google Code shutdown 2016-01-15). Perhaps update?

Comment: I think its now at https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor , right?