# Are the StackExchange pagedown/wmd help interfaces open-sourced anywhere?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, markdown, editor

I have the editor up and running as per [Where's the WMD editor open source project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/wheres-the-wmd-editor-open-source-project/71825)

But are the StackExchange pagedown/wmd help interfaces, i.e. the tabular help content and bouncing of the icons, available anywhere?

It would make a good plugin to open up, if it is not suitable to wrap into core.

Comment: I'd vote this up if I had the karma. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not; mostly for technical reasons:

1. The help texts are only pulled from the server on demand, and not included in the JavaScript (so when not needed, they don't waste bandwidth). And since the Pagedown editor is purely client-side JavaScript and does not make any assumptions concerning the server infrastructure, you can't really include it.
2. That code has a dependency on jQuery, because [it's really great and does all things](http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery). The Markdown editor, however, is supposed to work without jQuery.

Comment: That all makes good sense for why it can't be wrapped into core or released as a plugin, but I don't see why it couldn't be thrown on GitHub/alternative with a list of dependencies though?