# Does <Shift> + <Enter> create lists automatically if the line starts with a dash or a bullet?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, editor, list

I just noticed that if you have some text and you add a dash in front of the first character, then when you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> before any character in the text, then it gets rendered as a list.

This way, `-hello bla ble` becomes a list.

Steps to reproduce:

```
hello bla ble
```

```
-hello bla ble
```

```
 - hello bla ble
      ^
      cursor here, press Shift + Enter
```

Output:

```
 - hell

 - o bla ble
```

Same with bullets:

```
* hola adéu
```

Becomes

```
 * hola 
 * adéu
```

Comment: Ah, yes, it does, same for block quotes and code blocks.

Comment: @user289905 hadn't seen it documented anywhere

Comment: Also with numbered lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, it does. The [source code of the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71822/295232) is available [here on Google Code Archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/source/default/source) and the `Markdown.Editor.js` file contains the following lines:

```js
// Auto-indent on shift-enter
util.addEvent(inputBox, "keyup", function (key) {
    if (key.shiftKey && !key.ctrlKey && !key.metaKey) {
        var keyCode = key.charCode || key.keyCode;
        // Character 13 is Enter
        if (keyCode === 13) {
            var fakeButton = {};
            fakeButton.textOp = bindCommand("doAutoindent");
            doClick(fakeButton);
        }
    }
});
```

What does "doAutoindent" do? Well, a couple of lines below, there's some regex magic, which you could analyze further to determine under which conditions the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> works.

```js
// When making a list, hitting shift-enter will put your cursor on the next line
// at the current indent level.
commandProto.doAutoindent = function (chunk, postProcessing) {

    var commandMgr = this,
        fakeSelection = false;

    chunk.before = chunk.before.replace(/(\n|^)[ ]{0,3}([*+-]|\d+[.])[ \t]*\n$/, "\n\n");
    chunk.before = chunk.before.replace(/(\n|^)[ ]{0,3}>[ \t]*\n$/, "\n\n");
    chunk.before = chunk.before.replace(/(\n|^)[ \t]+\n$/, "\n\n");
    
    // There's no selection, end the cursor wasn't at the end of the line:
    // The user wants to split the current list item / code line / blockquote line
    // (for the latter it doesn't really matter) in two. Temporarily select the
    // (rest of the) line to achieve this.
    if (!chunk.selection && !/^[ \t]*(?:\n|$)/.test(chunk.after)) {
        chunk.after = chunk.after.replace(/^[^\n]*/, function (wholeMatch) {
            chunk.selection = wholeMatch;
            return "";
        });
        fakeSelection = true;
    }

    if (/(\n|^)[ ]{0,3}([*+-]|\d+[.])[ \t]+.*\n$/.test(chunk.before)) {
        if (commandMgr.doList) {
            commandMgr.doList(chunk);
        }
    }
    if (/(\n|^)[ ]{0,3}>[ \t]+.*\n$/.test(chunk.before)) {
        if (commandMgr.doBlockquote) {
            commandMgr.doBlockquote(chunk);
        }
    }
    if (/(\n|^)(\t|[ ]{4,}).*\n$/.test(chunk.before)) {
        if (commandMgr.doCode) {
            commandMgr.doCode(chunk);
        }
    }
    
    if (fakeSelection) {
        chunk.after = chunk.selection + chunk.after;
        chunk.selection = "";
    }
};
```

Note that the `/(\n|^)[ ]{0,3}([*+-]|\d+[.])[ \t]+.*\n$/` regex detects numbered lists with periods (`1.`, `2.`) etc. but *not* the new ones (`1)`, `2)`) we got with the [CommonMark migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/295232).

Comment: Cool! The fact that it does not work with `1)`, etc, suggests this is something older and undocumented to date. I thought for a sec that it could come with the CommonMark migration but it does not