# <s>links</s> are autocompleted on preview but not rendered when posted

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, markdown-preview, internal-links

Using question links conversion into links with titles, if you paste `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350279/209901` in a post, then it gets converted into a proper link to that question: [Does <Shift> + <Enter> create lists automatically if the line starts with a dash or a bullet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350279/209901).

Also, and according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188541/209901) in [Does Markdown have a way to express strikeout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63768/209901), `<s>bla</s>` strikes the text in it: <s>bla</s>.

However, I noticed that this does not work if within a `<s>` block of strikethrough without a space on both sides:

- <s>https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350279/209901</s>
  (this is `<s>https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350279/209901</s>`)
- <s>[Does <Shift> + <Enter> create lists automatically if the line starts with a dash or a bullet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350279/209901)</s> 
  (this is `<s> https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350279/209901 </s>`)

The funny thing is that it renders well in the preview:

> [image]

Comment: I've found similar behavior, at least on Math & Math meta SE, where if I use `<br>` in front of the link to expand, then in preview it works, but not when posted. However, adding a space after the `<br>` allows it to work in both preview & when posted. Interestingly, if I use `<s>Some text</s>` immediately after the link to expand, this strikethrough always works in both preview & when posted, plus doesn't affect whether or not the expansion of the link works properly. Thus, it seems the main issue may be the `>` being just before the link to expand.

Comment: @John, links appear to have some problem. In [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349717/771581) too, you'll find that the preview and actual results are different and spaces make a difference.

Comment: Gariman's tests: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349715/282094

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Why was this declined?

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog because in the duplicate they mention _With the bugfix in place, a URL appearing right after a colon `:`, a semicolon `;`, a hash `#` without any space will be rendered as a hyperlink in the preview and on the server._ Since `<s>` is not among the options included, this is implicitly declined.