# Quoted headings are rendered properly on preview but not when posted

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview, blockquote

With markdown, you can use some dashes for headings. For example, this:

```
Hello
----
this is some other text
```

renders as this:

### Hello

this is some other text

This is fine and works well. When I want to quote that text is when the problem arises, since this Markdown:

```
> Hello
> ----
> this is some other text
```

When written down shows well in the preview but not when posted:

> ### Hello
>
> this is some other text

---

As an example, see an screenshot of the preview:

> [image]

and a screenshot of the posted content, where the `----` becomes a `<hr>`:

[image]

Note a similar bug I also reported: [<s>links</s> are autocompleted on preview but not rendered when posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351092/209901).

Comment: This isn't a solution, per se... but using `#` instead of `---` is going to be more repeatable since the dashes are used for horizontal lines and headers.

Comment: indeed, thanks @Catija. I normally use `#` also, only that I found out about this situation when formatting [a post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35311/1674) today.

Comment: This is one of the cases where our client-side markdown renderer is behaving differently than our server-side renderer. As I see it the [CommonMark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#example-29) suggests that this example should indeed be a heading instead of a a horizontal rule. I'll file a bug with our server-side markdown library and see if we can make this consistent. In the meantime, using `#` is the way to avoid this.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSO: [Inconsistency between preview and actual snippet when adding quotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400831/4642212).

Comment: Note that there is a similar problem using === headings in quoted text.  These render as expected in the preview, but are shown as literal === characters in the actual post.

Comment: @Sonic the question was displaying a bug, why [the revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/351170/revisions) to _Rebake post so it shows correctly_? Now the post does not make sense. If you wanted to do so, you could have added a screenshot of how it showed incorrectly before the fix added yesterday, so people would understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in Markdig, the server-side Markdown renderer we're using. I just updated the version we use to the one including the bugfix for this specific issue. Moving forward, you should see a proper level-2 heading in blockquotes with the syntax you gave in your example.