# Why does my bigification inside a block quote show during preview but self-destruct when I accept changes?

Tags: support, markdown

When I block quote a bit of a post that contains a

### **Big Title**

generated by

```
**Big Title**
--
```

It shows as big while am previewing the post during edit. But as soon as I click *Save Changes* the appearance changes and the bigification disappears.

Similar behavior when the `**` marks are removed.

Is this (what I feel to be) unexpected behavior *by design?*

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46429/12102):

[image: screenshot of preview while editing] [image: screenshot of post after saving edits]

Comment: There's generally issues with using underlines for headers - I generally recommend that people use hashes for the specific header size they want to use instead.

Comment: @Catija I'll look into that. It appears that preview generates a better, more correct, *and yet unfortunately inaccurate view* of what the final post looks like. That might reflect a broader underlying issue that deserves attention. [Smith & Dale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_and_Dale)'s "SMITH: Doctor, it hurts when I do this. DALE: Don't do that." might not be the best way to approach this. :-)

Comment: Yeah - not arguing with that - but this is a support question and there's already [at least one bug report about a nearly identical issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351170/quoted-headings-are-rendered-properly-on-preview-but-not-when-posted#comment1175963_351170).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351170/quoted-headings-are-rendered-properly-on-preview-but-not-when-posted#comment1175963_351170) with this that is in our backlog to look into but we haven't gotten to it yet. Ham, one of our developers, stated the following in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351170/quoted-headings-are-rendered-properly-on-preview-but-not-when-posted#comment1179810_351170):

> This is one of the cases where our client-side markdown renderer is behaving differently than our server-side renderer. As I see it the [CommonMark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#example-29) suggests that this example should indeed be a heading instead of a a horizontal rule. I'll file a bug with our server-side markdown library and see if we can make this consistent. In the meantime, using `#` is the way to avoid this.

In the interim, the suggestion here is the best we have: at least when inside quotes, use hashes instead of a line.

Comment: This solved my problem, and good to hear that there is already a bug report! By trial-and-error (I don't really know markdown except what I learn by writing SE posts) I've found that two hash marks followed by a space (very important) works.  `>## Answer 2` followed by a block quoted blank line `>` Thanks!