# Why headers is not working under quote?

Tags: support, edits

I know that in order to make an header, you need to add === in the following line.

## This is an example.

However, sometimes you need to add an header under a quote, because it is part of the text you want to quote.

So I thought I can do something like that:

[image]

Which seems to work great in the preview, but then when publishing, this is the result:

[image]

Should that work? Am I doing something wrong? This is the post I used as a reference(I have edited it, so the current version has an header using ): https://stackoverflow.com/a/65394980/2359227

Comment: So... I can understand if y'all think this is separate since it uses equals signs instead of dashes but it seems, generally, to be the same issue.

Comment: @Catija I see now that it does work, am I wrong?

Comment: You aren't wrong! The error was on my part - I failed to put a space between the `>` and the `===` - this is still somewhat of an error since it renders in the preview as being a header but with the space the formatting works as expected. This is likely something we should fix in the preview, though, since I believe the space is necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My preferred way to make headers is with hashes:

> ### New Packages
>
> Content for the paragraph.

This works cleanly and plays nicely with all markdown.

```
> ## New Packages
>
> Content for the paragraph.
```

It also allows you to choose from three levels of header using single, double or triple hash marks.

As a note, this is part of a known issue - [Quoted headings are rendered properly on preview but not when posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351170/quoted-headings-are-rendered-properly-on-preview-but-not-when-posted) which is now fixed, so your formatting choice should work just fine now! I've tested this by editing your Stack Overflow post to the `====` formatting style and confirmed that it works now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use three hash signs to indicate a header as well, and it works within blockquotes:

```
> ### Test
> test
```

produces

> #### Test
>
> test

---

I'm not sure how this is supposed to work under CommonMark, it's interesting to see that something different happens when you use hyphens: `----` instead of equal signs:

```
> Test
> ----
> test
```

produces

> Test
>
> ---
>
> test

even though, as in your case, the preview renders it correctly.